# Connect a Logitech Brio using CAT-8 for middle run

Tags: usb, webcam

I am trying to connect a Logitech Brio webcam using the existing CAT-8 cabling that is ran from the wall to a floor monument in our conference room (rough in wall cable length - 16 ft).  For reference, the cable that the Logitech comes with has a USB-C that connects camera side, and a USB-A PC side.  The cable run of CAT-8 is a single run between these 2 end points, and is not connected to any switches, servers, etc.  I tried using 2 RJ45 to USB-C adapters for the end points, but I wasn't able to see the light turn on for the camera or find it on the PC.

I saw in another post on here that the USB to Ethernet adapter is not likely to work for a webcam, and they suggested an Active USB extender cable.  Unfortunately, I can't run a new cable through the existing conduit to the floor monument (limited space), so am looking for a solution that will allow us to connect to the camera with at least HD quality using the CAT-8/RJ45 configuration.

Adapters tried:  Ugreen USB C to Ethernet Adapter 1000Mbps
Computer end point connections: Would like USB-C and USB-A to be able to work via adapter, but most laptops that will be connected will have USB-C only.

I am open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make this work.

USB requires a host at one end [a computer] & a client at the other [peripheral]. USB-C on a computer can be pressed into service to use an Ethernet adaptor… but the camera at the other end can't do this. It's a client, not a host.
If you connect an ethernet adaptor to it, it has no clue what it's for, nor will it get any power. Ethernet alone doesn't carry power [PoE does, but that's not relevant to this instance.] The camera doesn't even know what Ethernet is, let alone how to connect to it, get an IP address...
It needs the host for both power & comms.

Comment: Would some sort of power injector at the camera end possibly work?  Or would there still be the issue of the camera not recieving the comms?

Comment: The camera has no idea what Ethernet is - I updated the answer. Primarily the issue is, *it's a client*. It has nothing that is required for it to be a host.

Comment: @LTfp - Your going to have to accepts a solution that allows USB to be ran by using CAT-8 Ethernet WILL NOT WORK with a USB device like your camera. So a `Ugreen USB C to Ethernet Adapter` will not work, and no, a power injector WILL not work.

Comment: Bummer, but thank you both for the speedy replies.